# React JS Google Maps API. Как скормить google map свой компонент со своей любой версткой?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, reactjs, компоненты, marker

Вот так создается объект карты:

```
        const map = new google.maps.Map(root, {
            zoom,
            center,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            ...styleOpts
        });
```

Я передаю объект карты в компонент маркера гугла через контекст

```
 this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position,
        icon: markerIcon
    });
```

И я хочу пробрасывать в маркер сверстанный свой компонент например такой, у которого так же описано поведение при клике на него.

```
<div className='Класс с картинкой например'>{ this.props.children }</div>
```

Помогите пожалуйста - как это сделать? Я уже знаю и про то, что обычные маркеры можно вертеть как хочешь и про их infowindow. Мне нужно именно выглядело примерно так:

```
<Map
   определенные props
    lng и lat центра
>
    <marker
       lng и lat
     >
       <markerAirline>
    </marker>
</Map>
```